# How to get ngValue of multiple select tags generated in the html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a list of roles, which has id, name, parent_id(self one) in JSON.

```
roles
```

I am displaying all the roles with their name and parent, where parent is a select input which on load shows the parent name using selected option with the parent id matching the role id.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <tr>
     <td>{{role.name}}</td>
     <td>
     <select (change)="changeParent($event)">
         <option></option>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let parent of roles">
               <option [selected]="role.parent==parent.id" 
                       [ngValue]="roles" [value]="parent.id">
                 {{parent.name}}
               </option>
         </ng-container>
     </select>
   </td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

On change of a option, I want to access the ngValue and the value of the option selected in the TS file to update the parent of the role in the API call, as I get the id of the role and the parent ID with which I can push the Patch.

Answer (score 0):

Write an (click) function in option tag something like this (click)=SomeFunction(role.id,parent.id)

Comment: We cannot add any events to options I reckon?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the HTML part a little bit. Added `multiple` in select input. Model assigned based on the role name `selectedRoles[role.name]`, so whenever you select multiple roles as parent, it will call the `changeParent($event)` function and on the console, you will be able to see which role contains which parents.

[image: HTML Output]

[image: Console Output]

**app.components.html:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let role of roles">
  <tr>
    <td>{{role.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedRoles[role.name]" (ngModelChange)="changeParent($event)">
        <ng-container>
          <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [selected]="selectedRoles[role.name].indexOf(role.id)" [value]="role.id">
            {{role.name}}
          </option>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

**app.components.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // assuming roles is the list you have stated 
  // in the problem description

  roles = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Admin',
      parent_id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'User',
      parent_id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Guest',
      parent_id: 3
    }
  ];

  // selectedRoles will be the model for the select
  // input in form

  selectedRoles = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // calling the initRolesModel function
    this.initRolesModel();
  }

  initRolesModel() {
    // mapping the parent roles with role name
    this.roles.forEach((role: any) => {
      this.selectedRoles[role.name] = [role.parent_id];
    });
  }

  changeParent($event) {
    console.log(this.selectedRoles);
  }

}
```

Give some time, change the code as you need. I have created a map between a role and their selected parent roles from the original list of roles.

In case you want to update the parent roles, coming from the server, you may have to do some additional works to make the same code work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `ngModel` on the `select` dropdown to bind the `parent_id`. This way you won't even need to specify the `selected` attribute since `ngModel` is already bound to `parent_id` and `changeParent` will also not be required since updating the dropdown will dynamically update `roles`.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="role.parent_id">
    <option *ngFor="let parent of roles" [ngValue]="parent.id">
        {{parent.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```